# Как правильно получить ноду текущего инпута в методе класса и передать в другой метод?

Tags: javascript, html

Внутри конструктора вешается обработчик событий на **input** который при срабатывании вызывает метод
**check** внутри которого должен вызываться метод **isValid(this)** который в свою очередь должен вернуть **ноду** текущего **input**, но вместо этого мне возвращает весь мой класс **myClass**.
Как правильно получить текущий input?

```
class myClass {
  constructor(setting) {
    let formEl = document.getElementById(setting.id);
    let formFields = formEl.elements;
    for (let i = 0; i < formFields.length; i++) {
      formFields[i].addEventListener("change", this.check.bind(this);
    } 
   }

  isValid(el){
   console.log(el)
  }
  check(){
    this.isValid(this)
  }
}
```

Полный пример кода https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-moon-m9kr6?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  check(evt) {
    this.isValid(evt.target);
  }
```